# Set combobox in dojo datagrid cell depands on value type

Tags: html, dojo, dojox.grid

Can anybody help me how to set Combobox in DataGrid (dojox/grid) cells programmatically for each cell in column separately?

Structure parameter: cellType does its job, but all cells in column inherit defined type.

With formatter function we can return Combobox object but it has different behaviour then Combobox inserted with cellType.

I'm thinking also about onStartEdit function but I do not have idea how to implement that.

What I want to achieve is that if in cell is value which is text then I want to show combobox with all possibilities. In case of value as a number than I don't want to show combobox at all.

Sample code: (Dojo version 1.9.11)

```
 require([
                        "dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore",
                        "dojo/store/Memory",
                        "dojox/grid/DataGrid",
                        "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
                        "dojo/dom",
                        "dojo/dom-construct",
                        "dijit/form/ComboBox", 
                        "dojox/grid/cells/dijit",
                        "dojo/dom-style",
                        "dojo/domReady!"],
                function(ItemFileReadStore, Memory, DataGrid, ObjectStore, dom, domConstruct, ComboBox, dijit, domStyle){

                    var dataArray = [];
                    var dataMemory = new Memory({data:dataArray});

                    var gridStruc = [];                             
                    gridStruc.push({name: 'Name', field: 'col1', width: '100px', editable: false});
                    gridStruc.push({name: 'Type', field: 'col2', width: '100px', editable: false});
                    gridStruc.push({name: 'Value (cellType)', field: 'col3', width: '100px', editable: true, cellType: 'dojox.grid.cells.ComboBox', options: ["Test1","Test2"]});
                    gridStruc.push({name: 'Value (formatter)', field: 'col4', width: '100px', editable: true, formatter: formatterCb});                 

                    var columnObj0 = {};
                    columnObj0["col1"] = "Voltage";
                    columnObj0["col2"] = "Number";
                    columnObj0["col3"] = "5";   
                    columnObj0["col4"] = "5";                       
                    dataMemory.put(columnObj0);
                    var columnObj1 = {};
                    columnObj1["col1"] = "Type";
                    columnObj1["col2"] = "Text";
                    columnObj1["col3"] = "THT"; 
                    columnObj1["col4"] = "THT";                     
                    dataMemory.put(columnObj1);
                    var columnObj2 = {};
                    columnObj2["col1"] = "Num. Reflow";
                    columnObj2["col2"] = "Number";
                    columnObj2["col3"] = "3";   
                    columnObj2["col4"] = "3";                       
                    dataMemory.put(columnObj2);
                    var columnObj3 = {};
                    columnObj3["col1"] = "Series";
                    columnObj3["col2"] = "Text";
                    columnObj3["col3"] = "CBK34";   
                    columnObj3["col4"] = "CBK34";                       
                    dataMemory.put(columnObj3);

                    var dataStore = new ObjectStore({ objectStore: dataMemory});

                    grid = new DataGrid({
                        store: dataStore,
                        structure: gridStruc
                    },"gridDiv");

                    grid.startup();                                 

                    function formatterCb(value, rowIndex, rowItem)
                    {                               
                        var storeItems=[];
                        storeItems.push({name: "Test1", value: "test1"});
                        storeItems.push({name: "Test2", value: "test2"});

                        var store = new ItemFileReadStore({data: {identifier:"name", items: storeItems}});

                        var w = new ComboBox({
                            label: "Use Input",
                            store: store,
                            value: value
                        });
                        w._destroyOnRemove = true;
                        return w;
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think defining formatter function may help.
Take a look at [this example](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html#formatting-a-date-field) from documentation

```
function formatCell(value){
    //perform your logic here
}

var layout = [
    {
        name: 'Cell1', 
        field: 'id'
    },
    {
        name: 'Cell2', 
        field: 'date',
        formatter: formatCell
    }
];
```

In your case it will be here:

```
gridStruc.push({name: 'Name', formatter: formatCell, field: 'col1', width: '100px', editable: false});
```

I have no idea why do you use array.push, but it doesn't matter in this case.

Also check [this tutorial](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/populating_datagrid/), there is an example how to put widget in cell. It may be helpful.

Comment: Thx for reply! Returning dijit.form widgets with formatter not bring desirable results at least for ComboBox. As I detected dojox.grid using expanded class cells.dijit for creating widgets (if we use cellType in structure) with proper features but I don't know how to use them with formatter (you can run my code and see differences between using dijit.form.ComboBox and dojox.grid.cells.ComboBox).